# I have an issue with building react app and webpack using Dockerfile

Tags: webpack, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I am preparing a Docker image with built react app using webpack. I probably miss something, becuase after `yarn build` is executed I receive an error about missing webpack. But I have webpack in `node_modules/.bin/webpack`, which is copied using `COPY . /web`

```
$ webpack --mode production
/bin/sh: webpack: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

I tried running `yarn` only, but this will not build the app, obviously, but I inspected the container to confirm file copy.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@mySweetApp/my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "My Swee App",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot"
  },
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as node

RUN mkdir -p /web

WORKDIR /web

#Copy dependency definition
COPY package.json /web

RUN yarn install

#Copy all files
COPY . /web

RUN yarn build
```

**File tree** (deleted not needed stuff)

```
  },├── .babelrc
├── docker
│   ├── default.conf
│   ├── .dockerignore
│   └── ssl
├── Dockerfile
├── node_modules
│   ├── @babel
│   ├── babel-core
│   ├── .bin
│   │   ├── eslint -> ../../../../node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js
│   │   ├── eslint-config-prettier-check -> ../../../../node_modules/eslint-config-prettier/bin/cli.js
│   │   ├── lingui -> ../../../../node_modules/@lingui/cli/lingui.js
│   │   ├── lint-staged -> ../../../../node_modules/lint-staged/index.js
│   │   ├── webpack -> ../../../../node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
│   │   ├── webpack-cli -> ../../../../node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
│   │   └── webpack-dev-server -> ../../../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
│   ├── .cache
│   ├── debug
│   ├── jsesc
│   ├── ms
│   └── source-map
├── package.json
├── src
└── webpack.config.js
```

I definitely miss some small thing here, could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably solved the issue, I notices those symlinks point to parent directories. I have to move dockerfile to different dir and copy more files to image.
I will update in case of any success.